# Failed to generate the debug symbols

Tags: ios, build, xamarin, ios8, dsym

After updated iOS 8 on mac OSX 10.9.4 using Xamarin 5.4 (build 240).

When run application on simulator application runs fine.

When I connect my device and run I got below error message.

```
Error MT5203: Failed to generate the debug symbols (dSYM directory). Please review the build log. (MT5203) (ProjectName)
```

before update Its run successfully on device and simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usually happens because you haven't agreed to the Xcode/iOS license.

It is easily fixed by launching Xcode once.

Comment: Thank You! Its now working for me!  I made mistake launching Xcode-Beta.